# What is this condition where you imagine a string retracing your path in space and that you feel compelled to untangle?

Tags: behavior, compulsive

There is a special condition of some people where they imagine a thread that retraces the path where they have been before and feel compelled to not entangle it.  They feel compelled to leave a place using the same entry where they entered.  They feel uncomfortable if they leave a car from a different door from where they came in, because that means now the thread is forever going thru the car.  That thread is flexible though, if they walk a full circle around a flagpole that isn't a problem as the thread can pass over the flaghole.  But anything forming a closed loop where you go thru would causes a concern.  They feel an urge to go back the other way.

A discussion about this can be found on reddit r/ocd:
https://www.reddit.com/r/OCD/comments/1ve309/invisible_thread_attached_to_my_back_am_i_the/

It triggers testimonies of people who have it or had it when they were younger.  It doesn't look uncommon.

My question is: Is there a name for this condition?  Has it been studied or described clinically?  Any reference?

**Background**

The reason I am asking this question is because of the xkcd strip
https://xkcd.com/2679/.

I understood this strip as related to the condition I described above.  I explained this on a site devoted to explain this comic strip, https://explainxkcd.com/2679/.  But the explanation was discarded because it wasn't backed by trustworthy sources.

So I am looking for references for research that has been done on this precise syndrome with an imaginary string, or just describing it, to show this is a real thing.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Has this question originated from the Reddit discussion or from someone you know? If so, [for a number of reasons outlined in this meta post](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/why-was-my-self-help-question-closed-as-off-topic) we can not, and will not, give advice or potential diagnoses for any specific individual. If you or anyone else has a question regarding personal mental health, advice from a doctor should be sought. For further information on how this site is supposed to work, what is on-topic or not, you can visit the [ask] page.

Comment: This is not about a diagnosis or searching for a therapy.  I edited the post to describe the reason behind the question.

Comment: Uhm. How common is this? I understood the Xkcd as purely absurdist, as some of his strips are. Have you tried actually asking the author rather than trying to guess what he was thinking?

Comment: @keshlam I have.  But since he is a quite successful cartoonist he is a bit difficult to reach.  I had no reply so far.  I don't know how common it is, but I have heard of it before.  The reddit threads are the only mentions I found on Internet, so, pretty uncommon.  But the reddit threads seem to trigger a few "me too" comments and likes.